# Determining $\sin(15)$, $\sin(32)$, $\cos(49)$, etc.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How do you in general find the trigonometric function values? I know how to find them for 30 45, and 60 using the 60-60-60 and 45-45-90 triangle but don't know for, say $\sin(15)$ or $\tan(75)$ or $\csc(50)$, etc.. I tried looking for how to do it but neither my textbook or any other place has a tutorial for it. I want to know how to find the exact values for all the trigonometric functions like $\sin x$, $\csc x$, ... opposed to looking it up or using calculator. According to my textbook, $\sin(15)=0.26$, $\tan(75)=3.73$, and $\csc(50)=1.31$ but doesn't show where those numbers came from, as if it was dropped from the Math heaven!

Comment: You can use similar methods used in this page for some angles:http://geometri-problemleri.blogspot.com.es/2013/02/some-useful-angle-aproximations.html

Comment: Hint: Use :

 $\cos(2x)=2\cos(x)^2-1,\ $
 $\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\sqrt{1-\sin(x)^2},\ $
 $\displaystyle\tan(2x)=\frac{2\tan(x)}{1-\tan(x)^2},\ $
 $\cdots$ (revert the expressions !).

Comment: Looks like the arguments you passed to the trigonometric functions are in degrees instead of radians. i.e. $\sin(15^{\circ})$ instead of $\sin(15\;\text{rad})$. You better fix your question. Expression like $\sin(15^{\circ})$ can be expressed in terms of radicals using half-angle formulae while $\sin(15\;\text{rad})$ cannot.

Answer (score 2):

Value of $\sin{x}$ with prescribed accuracy can be calculated from Taylor's representation
$$\sin{x}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}{\dfrac{(-1)^n x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}}$$ or infinite product
$$\sin{x}=x\prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}{\left(1-\dfrac{x^2}{\pi^2 n^2} \right)}.$$
For some partial cases numerous [trigonometric identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Infinite_product_formulae) can be used.

Answer (score 1):

The chords of the rational angles solve a series of equations, which one can derive from an *iso-series*, in the form  $T(n+1)=X.T(n)-T(n-1)$.  You then solve for the unique factor in each even number, and the chords of a $p$-gon solves this.   The process can be greatly accelerated, by using a *bignum* environment.

In any case, the exact expression of something like $cos(1°)$ solves some equation involving cube and fifth roots.  But you can get around things like this, too.

If one solves the value for a supplement chord, say $scho{15°} = (\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2})/2) = 1.93185165259$, the chords for subsequent angles, follow the same isoseries formula as above, with X = chord 1, $T(0) = scho(0) = 2$, and $X = T(1)=scho(15°)$, and subsequent $T(n) = scho(15n°)$.

Comment: +1... I tried experimenting and thinking about your answer.  I thought that I might be able to use the multiple angle formula to derive a recursive formula for some angles.  But, rather than reinvent the wheel, I was wondering if you tell me where I can learn more about this.  Are there books, websites, courses, etc. that talk about this?  Is there a name for this subject/topic?

Answer (score 0):

For some angles (such as 15 or 75 degrees), you can apply the formulas for [doubling and halving the angles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Double-angle.2C_triple-angle.2C_and_half-angle_formulae) and those for [sums and differences of angles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities). For example, if you know that $\sin x=0.4$, these formulas allow you to calculate $\sin 2x$ or $\sin 17x$ or $\sin \frac{11}{32}x$, ...

Unfortunately, such formulas are not powerful enough to calculate the values for arbitrary angle (e.g. $\sin 43$). For those, one needs to employ the real-analysis definition of $\sin x$ using the Taylor series which might be beyond the scope of what you have learned so far.